# Error installing apps

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I'm trying to install a game on the Play store, and I get the following error every time:

> Sorry, we had trouble processing your request. We're working on fixing the issue. Please try again later. [BM-PPH-01]

I've been trying to get this fixed for almost two months.  Android support directed me to the app developer's support, who in turn directed me back to Android.

It doesn't matter whether I attempt to install from my tablet (Toshiba AT300), my phone (HTC Evo 3D), or directly from the Play store.  I get the same error from all thee.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found on our sister site StackOverflow, with the question [Google Play Alpha App BM-PPH-01 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16618340/2533433):

> BM-PPH-01 error message is usually shown when there is an incompatibility between any of the three App,Google Pay, Device.
>
> The incompatibility can be the device's location such as Google play features not available when device is in China . An app can be restricted for downloading in US only.

This would explain why "try later" might not work in your case: if it's either your device or location, and you didn't change either of the two, the cause would have remained.

For more details (ans helpful links) see "over there".